# Laravel update via form model binding

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, model-binding

I have a little web app in which users can register, if they want to update their accounts later then a form is shown with all their info. via form model binding. I they save it and the username isn't changed, a problem occurs because in the validation it must be unique but it already exists (of course, they are updating, not creating). What would you do to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please share your code?

Normally here is what the code should look like.

```
    {{ Form::model($user, array('route' => 'user.edit', $user->id)) }}  

    <!-- name -->
    {{ Form::label('Full Name', 'Full Name') }}
    {{ Form::text('Full Name') }}

    <!-- email -->
    {{ Form::label('emailAddress', 'emailAddress') }}
    {{ Form::email('emailAddress') }}       

    {{ Form::submit('Update') }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

I'd recommend not binding username in your form or making it read only. I assume you will be storing user id or username in session anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I'm on my phone so I can't upload the code. I'm not storing user id or username on session, how would you do it? And what's the benefit of it? Ps: I already know how to do the form model binding

Comment: Does this user need to authenticate or login to your site first before updating their information?

Comment: They do need to login first to the site to update their information (this is already implemented)

Comment: If they need to login then you must be maintaining their session by a user id or a user name so you should use that for an update. To access logged in user you would simply do this $id = Auth::id(); Just don't bind your username in the forum.

Refer to this document http://laravel.com/docs/security and check out section "Accessing The Logged In User"